# Обход массива

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать следующею задачу: есть пустой массив, по нажатию кнопки должна выполниться функция, но прежде чем выполниться она должна проверить существует ли параметр переданный функции в массиве, если параметра нет в массиве то функция выполниться и этот параметр добавиться в массив, а если он уже есть в массиве то функция не выполняется, это нужно чтобы функция выполнялась для каждого параметра переданного ей один раз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проверить, если ли элемент в массиве, можно с помощью indexOf

```
function addUniq(arr, param) {
  if (arr.indexOf(param) !== -1) {
    return ; //уже есть, возвращаемся
  }

  arr.push(param); // еще нет, добавляем
}
```